# Difference between @something.value@ and ${something.value} in spring boot YAML

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

I am referring to code samples in the demos provided by spring-doc as [properties](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi-demos/tree/master/springdoc-openapi-data-rest) and [yaml](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi-demos/blob/master/springdoc-openapi-book-service/src/main/resources/application.yml), code samples provided below.

```
springdoc.version= @springdoc.version@
springdoc.swagger-ui.use-root-path=true
```

```yaml
springdoc:
  version: '@springdoc.version@'
  swagger-ui:
    use-root-path: true
```

I want to understand the difference between the way of mentioning `@springdoc.verison@` and `${springdoc.version}`. which is the standard for using it in yaml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the docs here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.x/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html

You will use @..@ in a application.yaml or application.properties to access values defined in maven's pom.xml file.

You will use ${...}  when your project is a Grade project.